# A question about the log of a rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, rational-functions

We have the rational function :
$$f(x)=\frac{(1+ix)^{n}-1}{(1-ix)^{n}-1}\;\;\;,\;\;n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$$
It's not hard to prove that :
$$\frac{(1+ix)^{n}-1}{(1-ix)^{n}-1}=(-1)^{n}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{x+i(\xi_{n}^{k}-1)}{x-i(\xi_{n}^{k}-1)}\;\;\;,\;\;\xi_{n}^{k}=e^{2\pi i k/n}$$
Now we want to compute $\log f(x)$ for $x>0$. The logarithm of the individual factors can be written as :

$$\log\left(\frac{x+i(\xi_{n}^{k}-1)}{x-i(\xi_{n}^{k}-1)}\right)=2i\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{1-\xi_{n}^{k}}\right)+i\pi;\;\;\;\;x>0$$
So, one would expect:
$$\log f(x)=-i\pi+2i\pi n+2i\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{1-\xi_{n}^{k}}\right)$$
But it looks nothing like what wolframalpha returns. What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: what does WA return?

Comment: Could you provide what wolframalpha returned?  Your answer might actually be the same, but we don't know what we're comparing to, to answer the question.

Comment: Does $\tan^{-1}=\cot\text{ or }\arctan$?

Comment: $\tan^{-1}$ is $\arctan$

Comment: WF returns the difference as a sum of step functions [linkl](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(((1%2Bix)%5E(5)-1)%2F((1-ix)%5E(5)-1))-2*i*sum%5Barctan(x%2F(1-e%5E(2*pi*i*k%2F5))),%7Bk,1,4%7D%5D%2Bi*pi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, if you use the standard branch of $\log$ used by Wolfram Alpha, your third identity should read:

$$\log\left(\frac{x+i(\xi_{n}^{k}-1)}{x-i(\xi_{n}^{k}-1)}\right)=2i\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{1-\xi_{n}^{k}}\right)-\pi i,\quad x>0.$$

Compare for exampe: [arctan](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-I%20%5C%5BPi%5D%20%2B%202%20I%20ArcTan%5B1%2F(1%20-%20E%5E((I%20%5C%5BPi%5D)%2F3))%5D) and [log](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5B(1%20%2B%20I%20(-1%20%2B%20E%5E((I%20%5C%5BPi%5D)%2F3)))%2F(1%20-%20I%20(-1%20%2B%20E%5E((I%20%5C%5BPi%5D)%2F3)))%5D).

You are using a branch of the logarithm, so in general it is not true that $\log (ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$. You can check that the difference between the corrected expression 
$$\log f(x)=-\pi(n-1)i + 2i\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{1-\xi_{n}^{k}}\right),$$
and the original $\log f(x)$ is a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: i still don't understand why WA returns the above + some sort of a step function !! [here is an example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5Blog(((1%2Bix)%5E(4)-1)%2F((1-ix)%5E(4)-1))%2B3*pi*i-2*i*arctan(x%2F(1-e%5E(2*pi*i%2F4)))-2*i*arctan(x%2F(1-e%5E(2*pi*i*2%2F4)))-2*i*arctan(x%2F(1-e%5E(2*pi*i*3%2F4))),%7Bx,0,20%7D%5D)

Comment: Like I said, $\log(ab) \ne \log(a) + \log(b)$, for example $\log(e^{\pi i} \cdot e^{\pi i}) = 0$, and $\log(e^{\pi i}) = \pi i$. So the difference in general is going to be a multiple of $\pi i$.

Comment: i understand that. but what are the points at which there is a step difference by a multiple of $\pi i$

Comment: The jumps are at the points where the sum is equal to a multiple of $\pi i$.